# Network Project Question

Tags: lan

I'm working on a network design proposal for a class that deals with a hypothetical school building that needs to establish a new LAN for students and faculty with internet access.

Anyway, this is the part I'm confused about - The school needs a primary connection of at least 40 Mbps, but it cannot be through cable, DSL, or FIOS. It also needs a backup line of at least 20 Mbps.

So, other than cable, DSL, and fiber optic, what other options would there even be? We've been made aware of some WAN options (T3, etc.), but as far as I can tell those wouldn't be applicable here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "cable, DSL, or FIOS" means "residential" services. This school would, therefore, need a commercial, dedicated internet service: T1, T3, OC3, Metro-Ethernet, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, residential broadband is off-limits.  **Business or enterprise grade Direct Internet Access (DIA)** is the direction you need to seek out.  Consider carrier ethernet services delivered over twisted-pair (*Base-T), coax (T3), or fiber (1000Base-X) that provide symmetrical bandwidth and better service level agreements (SLAs).